# Is it possible to get all added records after SaveChanges in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a `foreach` loop that adds entities to a DB context in EF6, this way:

```
foreach (var asistencia in asistencias)
{
    var newEntity = new Entity()
    parentEntity.NewEntity.Add(newEntity);  // parentEntity is the parent record.
}

await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now, I need to do something with the identity fields of the new records.

As a patch, I created a `List` before the `foreach` loop and before the closing `}` of the loop, I called `newElements.Add(newEntity)`

Then I did a `foreach` in the `newElements` list and I could get the new identity numbers.

Is there a more elegant way to do that? For example, by mean of a context method to retrieve the new added records?

Comment: Do you still have access to `parentEntity.NewEntity`? Doesn't that contain everything you want? Can you provide a [mre]? The property names and the description of your code isn't clear.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes... but `parentEntity.NewEntity` contains all child records, including old ones. I only need new records.

Comment: At the T-SQL level, if you want to do some "post-processing after insert", a typical solution is to write a [trigger function](https://www.sqlshack.com/triggers-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Without _showing_ your attempt, I don't see anything wrong with what you've tried.

Comment: @paulsm4 I have thought about that, but since EF6 is tracking the entities, maybe this can be done using EF6. I have found something about the state of a record,  but I am not sure it could help.

Comment: @gunr2171 This is not an error. In fact, my solution works perfectly. I was just wondering if I can do that using EF6 entity tracking capabilities, instead of creating a new  `List<>` to get the added records.

Comment: You might want to look at [EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered): https://onthedrift.com/posts/efcore-triggered-part1/

Comment: Perhaps the next link is useful: [entityframeworktutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-get-id-of-saved-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)